# Unable to associate an SSL certificate with a binding in IIS programmatically after importing it during an InstallShield installation

Tags: c#, ssl, iis, installshield, pfx

I have an InstallShield installation that deploys a website to IIS on a Windows machine. It has always deployed the website with an HTTP binding. I am adding support for deploying the website using HTTPS and I am having some difficulty getting it to work in all cases. I am allowing the user to either select an already installed certificate from the "Personal" or "Web Hosting" stores for the local machine, or select a PFX file from the file system and provide the password. Either way, I obtain the thumbprint of the certificate. As long as the user chooses an SSL certificate that is already in the store, it works as expected. However, if the user chooses to select a PFX file & enter the password, I am able to successfully import the certificate into the "Web Hosting" store, but when I try to add the https binding and associate the certificate to it, I receive the following exception when committing the changes:

"A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070520)"

The https binding is added successfully, and even if I try to associate the certificate using IIS I get the same message, which tells me it may be related to the Import process more than the Binding process.
I have implemented a handful of methods in a managed library in C# and include the library in the installer project, and created CustomActions in the InstallShield project to invoke these methods.  All CustomActions run in Deferred mode in System context, so it has admin rights. I have tons of logging output for troubleshooting purposes, and can see that everything happens without issues, right up to the point that the CommitChanges() method is called when adding the https binding to the website.
Here is my code. I have tried about 10 variations of this as I have found different potential solutions online, but none has been 100% successful. Current state is what I have been most successful with so far (the FindCertificate() method returns a X509Certificate2 object and the name of the store where it was found, and works properly):

```
/// <summary>
/// Imports a SSL certificate from a file with a password to the specified store on the Local Machine
/// </summary>
/// <param name="customActionData">Semi-colon delimited list containing the certificate path/filename, password, and store name</param>
/// <returns>
/// 1=Success; 0=Invalid arguments; -1=Cert file not found; -100=Exception occurred
/// </returns>
public static Int32 ImportCertificateFromFile(string customActionData)
{
    var args = customActionData.Split(new char[] { ';' });
    if (args.Length != 3)
        return 0;

    var certFile = args[0].Replace("\\", "\\\\");
    var password = args[1];
    var storeName = args[2];

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(certFile) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(storeName))
        return 0;

    if (System.IO.File.Exists(certFile))
    {
        try
        {
            using (var store = new X509Store(storeName, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
            {
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
                var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certFile, password);
                store.Add(certificate);
                return 1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return -100;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

/// <summary>
/// Adds a binding to a website
/// </summary>
/// <param name="customActionData">Semi-colon delimited list containing the website name, IP address, port, host header, protocol, and certificate thumbprint for the binding to add</param>
/// <returns>
/// 1=Success; 0=Invalid arguments; -1=Website not found; -100=Exception occurred
/// </returns>
public static Int32 AddWebsiteBinding(string customActionData)
{
    var args = customActionData.Split(new char[] { ';' });
    if (args.Length != 6)
        return 0;

    var siteName = args[0];
    var ipAddress = args[1];
    var port = args[2];
    var hostHeader = args[3];
    var protocol = args[4].ToLower();
    var thumbprint = args[5];

    var ret = 1;
    var serverManager = new ServerManager();
    var webSite = serverManager.Sites.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == siteName);
    if (!(webSite is null))
    {
        try
        {
            var binding = webSite.Bindings.CreateElement("binding");
            binding.Protocol = protocol;
            binding.BindingInformation = $"{ipAddress}:{port}:{hostHeader}";

            // add SSL certificate if thumbprint was provided
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(thumbprint))
            {
                var (cert, storeName) = FindCertificate(thumbprint);

                if (!(cert is null))
                {
                    binding.CertificateHash = cert.GetCertHash();
                    binding.CertificateStoreName = storeName;
                }
            }

            webSite.Bindings.Add(binding);
            serverManager.CommitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ret = -100;
        }
    }
    else
        ret = -1;

    return ret;
}
```

The certificates I am using for testing purposes are self-signed certificates generated using IIS on the machine where the testing is being done, and then the certificates wer exported to .pfx files and given a password. I have tried creating certificates in "Personal" and "Web Hosting" stores, but I don't see any difference once exported to a .pfx file and imported into the "Web Hosting" store.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will solve your issue, but I have encountered the same error in some code we have for setting up our local dev environments' websites with certs through an app to get us started quickly.  It appeared to be because our certificates were not set up correctly when creating the websites.  In my case I had to delete the cert first through certlm to make sure the new one was imported in code properly.

Then, in our code to import certificates, we set the key storage flags in the following way (assuming your certificate was created with the option to allow it to be exported):

```
// Certificate needs to be exportable with the private key to import into IIS
var keyStorageFlags = X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet;

// Store location and key storage flag need to match to import into IIS - this is for our developer environments, probably not for your installshield scenario
if (storeLocation == StoreLocation.LocalMachine)
{
    keyStorageFlags |= X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet;
}
```

It seems that it would be investigating these [X509KeyStorageFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509keystorageflags?view=net-6.0) enum options for your scenarios...this worked for our pfx files, but yours may not have been created with the same settings.